# TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined in react react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

This is my loginform.js i am trying to submit the data by using state. 
And the login form get renders in loginpage.js like this 
in loginPage.js submit the data to redux and then i push the page to ("/") by using then.

but problem is it never redirects to home instead it gives some error like this

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
LoginPage._this.submit
C:/projects/login/login-react/src/components/pages/LoginPage.js:11
   8 | import './login.css';
   9 | 
  10 | class LoginPage extends React.Component {
> 11 |   submit = data =>
  12 |     this.props.login(data).then(() => this.props.history.push("/"));
  13 | 
  14 |   render() {
View compiled
LoginForm._this.onSubmit
C:/projects/login/login-react/src/components/forms/LoginForm.js:24
  21 | this.setState({errors});
  22 | if(Object.keys(errors).length === 0) {
  23 |   this.setState({loading: true});
> 24 |   this.props
  25 |     .submit(this.state.data)
  26 |     .catch(err =>
  27 |       this.setState({errors: err.response.data.errors, loading: false})
View compiled
▶ 23 stack frames were collapsed.
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your brow
```

> loginPage.js

```
class LoginPage extends React.Component {
  submit = data =>
    this.props.login(data).then(() => this.props.history.push("/"));
```

> login form.js

```
onSubmit = () => {
        const errors = this.validate(this.state.data);
        this.setState({errors});
        if(Object.keys(errors).length === 0) {
          this.setState({loading: true});
          this.props
            .submit(this.state.data)
            .catch(err =>
              this.setState({errors: err.response.data.errors, loading: false})
            );
        }
      };
```

> This how login looks like

```
export const login = credentials => dispatch =>{
  api.user.login(credentials).then(user=> {
    localStorage.loginToken = user.token;
    dispatch(userLoggedIn(user));
  });
}
```

I want to know is there any other way to do this or how can i fix this?

Comment: How does the login prop look lile that you pass into the component?

Comment: i updated my question with login props

Comment: can you tell me any other way of doing this  submit form and then redirect the page to somewhere and catch errors as well.